# Entity Framework - Mapping subclasses to existing tables with different keys

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a legacy system that I am hoping to use EF to clean up the mess of ADO code it uses for data access.

The system uses the following class hierachy: Sponsors which are Members which are People.  In the database, each class has it's own table, each with its own key.

```
Person
PersonId (PK)
Name

Member
MemberId (PK)
PersonId (FK)

Sponsor
SponsorId (PK)
MemberId (FK)

Mappings
Person
ToTable("Person");
HasKey(p => p.Id).Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("PersonId").IsRequired();

Member
ToTable("Member");
HasKey(m => m.MemberId).Property(m => m.MemberId).HasColumnName("MemberId").IsRequired();

Sponsor
ToTable("ChapterSponsor");
HasKey(cs => cs.MemberId).Property(cs => cs.MemberId).HasColumnName("MemberId").IsRequired();
```

I can map the Person and Member classes fine.  But when I try to map the Sponsor class, I get an error because it is trying to find a field named PersonId on the Sponsor table.

Is it possible to tell EF that the Sponsor query needs to join using the MemberId Foreign Key?  Or is this poor db structure not going to work with EF?

Comment: You can use fluent API this way: `Sponsor.HasRequired(x => x.Member).WithMany(x => x.Sponsors).HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberId);`

Comment: Great resource about fluent API is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx